# Teaching Mavericks' Text-To-Speech how to pronounce

Tags: voice

I find the best way to proof read a piece of text (such as an email message) is by having my computer read back to me what I have written.  I highlight the piece of text, right click->Speech->Start speaking.

Sometimes, I find that it doesn't pronounce words correctly.  I found a built-in app (~\Applications\Utilities\VoiceOver Utility)
Under speech, and the tab Pronunciation, where ostensibly I can tell the text-to-speech engine how to phonetically pronounce a word.

For some reason, the text-to-speech simply doesn't update, and continues to mispronounce words I have already entered into the dictionary.  I've tried quitting my application, I've tried restarting my computer.. I just can't understand why it's not working.  Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the pronunciation table of the Voice Over Utility only works when using the Voice Over feature, but not in the 'normal' text-to-speech feature. It's sad.

Answer (score 0):

There are several VoiceOver property lists in ~/Library/Preferences

Try moving all of them out of there onto your Desktop, then restarting your computer, then setting up the VoiceOver as you want.

If it works, delete the files you moved. If it doesn't work, you can copy them back if you want.

Comment: It doesn't work.